# Problemas com enconding SQL x PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, encode

estou com o seguinte problema: Meus arquivos estão saíndo com problemas de acentuação, minhas tabelas utilizam utf-8 como encondig, os arquivos html tem a marcação para utf-8 e mesmo assim os acentos não funcionam:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://pankaimoveis.com.br/app/" />
<title>Panka Im�veis | Agilidade e Confiança</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

nos arquivos PHP uso também:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
@header( "Cache-Control: max-age=0" );
@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

e no .htacess está assim:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8

<Files ~ "\.html?$">  
     Header set Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
</Files>
```

Alguém sabe oque pode ser além disso tudo?

Answer (score -2):

Tente usar no seu header

> ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

Comment: Não funcionou ainda assim, coloquei no header, no html, seria isso?

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo index? index.php ou index.html? Se for index.php, tente colocar <?php ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); ?>